# Issue with Code Contracts on Generic Interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, code-contracts

I am experiencing an issue involving contracts for a generic interface.  I have two generic interfaces, each with a single method which has a single precondition (`Requires` contract).  The contract for the first interface works as expected: the precondition is propagated to implemenation classes, and the interface method is adorned appropriately (via the Code Contracts Editor Extension). The contract for the second interface is not detected, but the code is nearly identical between the two interface/contract pairs.

```
//
// Example working as expected
//

[ContractClass(typeof(IExporterContract<>))]
public interface IExporter<in TInput> 
    where TInput : class
{
    // Shows adornment "requires obj != null"; contracts propogate
    void Export(TInput obj);
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IExporter<>))]
abstract class IExporterContract<TInput> : IExporter<TInput>
    where TInput : class
{
    public void Export(TInput obj)
    {
        Contract.Requires(obj != null);
    }
}


// 
// Example with unexpected behavior
//

[ContractClass(typeof(IParserContract<>))]
public interface IParser<out TOutput>
    where TOutput : class
{
    // Workbook is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

    // Does not show adornment "requires workbook != null"; contracts do not propogate
    TOutput Parse(Workbook workbook);
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IParser<>))]
abstract class IParserContract<TOutput> : IParser<TOutput>
    where TOutput : class
{
    public TOutput Parse(Workbook workbook)
    {
        Contract.Requires(workbook != null);
        return default(TOutput);
    }
}
```

Of note, any interface in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.*` causes this behavior. Using any other type, everything works as expected.  I'm unaware of why this is, however.

**EDIT:** as [Porges pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9103073/1183544), the contracts are being written (confirmed via IL), so this seems to be specific to the Code Contracts Editor extension.

Answer (score 2):

I can't replicate this. Given this code (along with your example):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var g = new Bar();
        g.Parse(null);
        var f = new Foo();
        f.Export(null);
    }
}

public class Foo : IExporter<Foo>
{
    public void Export(Foo obj)
    {
    }
}
public class Bar : IParser<Bar>
{
    public Bar Parse(Workbook workbook)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The contract is propagated as expected (decompiled via Reflector):

```
public Bar Parse(Workbook workbook)
{
    __ContractsRuntime.Requires(workbook != null, null, "workbook != null");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You're right, it does shows up in the IL; I hadn't checked.  Do you have the Code Contracts Editor Extension installed?  I'm curious to see if the contract adornments show up for you.

Comment: It doesn't show me anything for `Parse`. However when I mouse over `Export` it says "This member has no contracts", which is weird. Maybe there's some incompatibility with the latest CC version?